# Can I execute a scalar query in EF 4.1?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to execute a scalar-valued query using EF 4.1?

I've tried:

```
     ObjectQuery<int> query = new ObjectQuery<int>("select count(*) from myTable", _context);
     var result = query.Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking);
     return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

but it returns an error: `The query syntax is not valid. Near term '*'`

Is the only way to execute a scalar-valued query to call a stored proc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are thinking of entity framework as an "ADO.net 2.0" rather than the ORM that it is.

Rather than using it to execute SQL queries, I'd recommend using the standard entity framework Data container and using a LINQ query, as is intended with entity framework.  Then it would simply be something like

```
    myDataContainerInstance.myTable.Count()
```

ObjectQuery isn't analogous to the ADO.net command and doesn't execute SQL statements. Instead it is used to define queries against the object model directly.  The (*) isn't valid because it isn't SQL.

Comment: Well, that was just an example - I need to do a complex join across multiple tables including a couple of many-to-many maps, and figured that it would be easier and probably more efficient to execute a query directly.

Comment: @chris You have two options.  You could either write a LINQ query that performs the joins appropriately (preferably without the join keyword by using implicit joins supported in LINQ) or, write a stored proc.  If you are simply joining across multiple tables (the many to many maps not withstanding) you could probably create a fairly efficient query in LINQ.  If temp tables, logic, or simply fine tuning of the query are needed, then the stored proc is your best bet.