# Executing table-less SQL in MVC4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, getdate

What is the best practice for executing a generic, table-less SQL query within an MVC architecture?

I'm trying to use commands such as these:

```
SELECT getdate();
SELECT user;
```

**Update:**
This is actually for part of another project that co-exists alongside the MVC project. All of my tables so far are mapped using edmx from an existing database.

I'd like to use the date from the database in some internal calculations, rather than using the date from the server where the application/site are installed. My formulas go down to the milliseconds, and the time difference between the two servers involved throws off the math.

Comment: That depends on your persistence layer. ASP.NET MVC does not imply a specific persistence layer.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do.. can you provide more details? any reason you can't use `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Assuming you are using EF, would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569396/can-i-execute-a-scalar-query-in-ef-4-1) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement them via Dapper:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
{
    DateTime getDate = connection.Query<DateTime>("select getdate()").Single();
}
```

Query is an extension method that accepts a Type to map to and Single() gives you a scalar value.

Dapper is the lightweight Orm by the guys on StackOverflow: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I was supposed to create more objects in the model or not, but this seems to do the job quite nicely.

Comment: @user373203 Awesome. Doing it via EF seemed like overkill to me. If you are looking for performance enhancements in the future, might want to consider dapper for all of your EF needs. There are pros and cons, but it is worth a look.